# fprintf misunderstandings and unhandled exception

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Here a piece of code:

```
long long someNumber;
...

do{
    ...
    scanf("%d", &someNumber);
    ...
} while (...);
fprintf(someFile, "%d", someNumber);
```

I need to read a number which contains 11 chars. I've tried all scanf() and fprintf() modes like "%Ld", "%lld", etc. but the result always is not what I printed. But it is not even my problem.
Then VS gives me an error when I'm typing ENTER:
*"Unhandled exception at 0x54A0F365 (msvcr120d.dll) in proj2.2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000A."*
It opens "output.c" and refers to the line:

```
while ((ch = *format++) != _T('\0') && charsout >= 0) {
```

Actually, it prints a wrong number into file. But an error doesn't allow to continue the work of the program. What is happenening ? Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `std::cin`? That would just work, without needing to guess the command string.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? You've tagged the question with both, but `fprintf` is more C-like.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I need to do this in C. This task was given from my teacher

Comment: @EMBLEM, I'm using C

Comment: Then why did you tag C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx), the correct data type specifier for type `long long` is `ll`.  You need to use this both with `scanf()` and with `printf()`:

```
long long someNumber;

scanf("%lld", &someNumber);
printf("%lld", someNumber);
```

If fixing the field specifier as above does not resolve your issue, then you have an additional problem somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The format for reading a `long long` is `"%lld"`. Use

```
scanf("%lld", &someNumber);
```

Use the same format for writing it out too.

```
fprintf(someFile, "%lld", someNumber);
```